# How do I prevent the copy constructor being called at the end of the for_each?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

In the following code I was expecting to see `COD` but the actual output was `CODD`. I eventually determined that there was a hidden call to the copy constructor and so the output is now `COUDD`.

While I have discovered why the extra destructor call I don't understand why it is being generated and that is preventing me from fixing it. I think it must be from the `for_each` returning the unary function but since I am not passing or returning by value (or I don't think I am) then the copy constructor should not be called. Everything should be by reference. I could use a pointer but since the `test_enc` object should be scope for the duration of the call to `for_each` then reference is nicer.

```
struct test_enc
{
    test_enc(std::string& ref) : ref_(ref) {
        ref_.push_back('C');
    }
    test_enc(const test_enc& other) : ref_(other.ref_) {
        ref_.push_back('U');
    }
    ~test_enc() {
        ref_.push_back('D');
    }
    void operator()(const char byte) {
        ref_.push_back('O');
    }
    test_enc& operator=(const test_enc&) = delete;
    std::string& ref_;
};

TEST(CheckTestEncoderEncodesExactlyOneByte)
{
    const std::string unencoded_string("M");
    std::string encoded_string;
    std::for_each(unencoded_string.begin(), unencoded_string.end(), test_enc(encoded_string));
    CHECK_EQUAL(3U, encoded_string.size());
    CHECK_EQUAL("COD", encoded_string); // get "COUDD"
}
```

**How can I call test_enc without the unwanted copy constructor?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) takes its unary functor by value. So you cannot avoid making a copy, but you can mimic reference semantics by using an [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
#include <functional>

std::string encoded_string;
test_encoded test_str(encoded_string);
std::for_each(unencoded_string.begin(), 
              unencoded_string.end(), 
              std::ref(test_str));
```

Comment: That fails because the encoding won't complete until after the test_str goes out of scope thus failing.  I could start placing braces around everything to force scope but that won't help in the real world.

Comment: @graham.reeds So how do you intend to use this type? I see no way, other than adding a scope to force the destructor call.

Comment: Well it is an encoder (for BaseN) and the trailing bytes plus padding occurs in the destructor. Why is the copy constructor being called?

Comment: @graham.reeds because `std::for_each` takes the functor by value. I added a sentence mentioning that. But I don't understand how you expect it to take a reference *and* for the destructor to get called.

Comment: Because I thought the encoder object would last as long as the `for_each` was running and once complete the final destructor would be called clearing it up. If you add additional characters to `unencoded_string` you get `COOUDD`,`COOOUDD` etc., proving the idea is correct apart from the final copy/destructor.

Comment: @graham.reeds Have you tried adding a no-op move constructor?

Comment: I hadn't. Forgot entirely about them. That fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using an `std::reference_wrapper` perhaps?

```
test_enc func(encoded_string);
std::for_each(unencoded_string.begin(), unencoded_string.end(),
              std::ref(func));
```

The wrapper behaves similar to a reference but allows it to be copied as needed (without affecting the underlying object).

Comment: That won't play nicely with the non-const `test_enc::operator()`. I think you need to pass an lvalue to `std::ref`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::for_each` returns `std::move(f)`. Your test_enc is not movable, so a copy is returned. Add move constructor and move assignment operator to prevent the copy.